# LBNF, C function declaration / definition, reduce reduce conflict

Tags: c++, c, context-free-grammar, bnf, bnfc

I'm trying to represent in LBNF that C/C++ function declarations have the following (approximate) form (`<sym>` denotes optionallity, and [rule] is a zero-or-more list):

```
type ident ( [type <id>] );
```

While function definitions have the form:

```
type ident ( [type id] ) { [stmt] }
```

Currently, I have the following LBNF:

```
entrypoints Program ;
Program.   Program ::= [TopDef] ;

FnDef.     TopDef ::= Type Ident "(" [Arg] ")" Block ;
FnDecl.    TopDef ::= Type Ident "(" [Par] ")" ";" ;
separator nonempty TopDef "" ;

Param.     Par ::= Type ;
NParam.    Par ::= Type Ident ;
separator Par "," ;

Arg.       Arg ::= Type Ident;
separator  Arg "," ;

-- Types ---------------------------------------------------

Int.       Type ::= "int" ;
--- more types...
separator  Type "," ;
```

Which causes reduce/reduce conflicts as expected.
Is there a way to solve this in the parser / lexer?

I could solve it with the following grammar:

```
FnDef.     TopDef ::= Type Ident "(" [Arg] ")" Block ;
FnDecl.    TopDef ::= Type Ident "(" [Arg] ")" ";" ;
separator nonempty TopDef "" ;

Arg.       Arg ::= Type Ident;
Arg.       Arg ::= Type;
separator  Arg "," ;
```

And then check in the type checker that function definitions have identifiers for each argument, but this feels less satisfying...

How is this typically handled in a language like C ?

Comment: C or C++.  There are decorators in C++ that do not exist in C.

Comment: @NathanOliver let's consider an imaginary and much more simpler language that is neither C or C++. What my question is about is just the two forms above and the distinction between them.

Comment: I think you meant that you are using `<...>` for optionality, since the `(` and `)` are clearly intended to be input symbols.... Oh, you did but you didn't notice that `<sym>` is sufficiently like HTML markup that markdown deletes it.

Comment: @rici Yeah, thanks for the markup fix =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way you mention which you find unsatisfying is, in fact, the way it's usually accomplished.

But you can produce an LALR(1) grammar which is precise. Here's a complete bison specification without conflicts:

```
%token TYPE ID
%%
prog       : 
           | prog decl ';'
decl       : TYPE ID def_list block
           | TYPE ID def_list ';'
           | TYPE ID dec_list ';'
block      : '{' prog '}'
def_list   : '(' ')'
           | '(' type_ids ')'
dec_list   : '(' type_opt_ids ')'
type_opt_id: type_only
           | type_id
type_ids   : type_id
           | type_ids ',' type_id
type_opt_ids
           : type_only
           | type_ids ',' type_only  /* SEE BELOW */
           | type_opt_ids ',' type_opt_id
type_id    : TYPE ID
type_only  : TYPE
```

The key is to avoid forcing the parser to make a decision. As it is passing over the list of parameters, it can keep reducing a `type_opt_ids` as long as it doesn't hit an anonymous parameter. If it hits one,  it reduces a `type_ids` and continues for the rest of the parameters, whether they are anonymous or not. At the end, the definition only allows `type_ids` but the declaration (explicitly) accepts either.

To make that work, the semantic type for `type_id` and `type_only` would need to be the same, since both `type_ids` and `type_opt_ids` must be lists of that type. Otherwise, you would need to convert `type_ids` to `type_opt_ids` in the production marked with `/* SEE BELOW */`

(I apologize for not converting that to your formalism, but I wanted to test it with bison to verify that it is, in fact, conflict-free. It should be easy enough to convert.)

---

Note that C++ is happy to allow function definitions without parameter names, but C is not. On the other hand, C allows function definitions without types, or with the type declarations between the parameter-name list and the body. But that's a side issue, really.

Comment: Great answer. No need to apologize, I need some challenge after all. But I guess now I'll do it in the type checker instead since it's the usual way =)